# Updating a plot doesn't clear old plots, if event trigger came from another figure?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am updating a line plot. There is an event trigger that starts this updating. If the trigger came from the figure that contains the plot, everything is fine. However, if the trigger came from another figure, then weird results happen: the line that's been updated appears to leave its trace uncleared.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):

    for ii in np.linspace(0., np.pi, 100):
        y1 = y * np.sin(ii)
        line1.set_ydata(y1)
        ax.draw_artist(line1)
        line2.set_ydata(-y1)
        ax2.draw_artist(line2)
        ax2.set_ylim(y1.min(), y1.max())
        fig.canvas.update()
        plt.pause(0.1)


x = np.linspace(0., 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
line1 = ax.plot(x, y)[0]

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
line2 = ax2.plot(x, y)[0]


fig2 = plt.figure()

cid = fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

What I see on screen:

[image: wrong]

Please note, if you resize the plot, or save it as figure, then all the residue image will be gone.

On the other hand, if change one line to:

```
cid = fig2.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

then it is correct. The animation works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `fig.canvas.update()` would do. If you replace that line by

```
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

it should work as expected. In that case you would not need to draw the artists individually.